# Ruby on rails does not clear browser cache when session ends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, angular-cache

I am using Devise gem to handle login/logout in my website. In client i use AngularJS cache is DSCacheFactory.

I have an issue about browser cache or angularJS cache. It is cache still stores old value when session ended.

Example:

1. login user A
2. logout user A
3. login user B
   website shows user A.

I expect that after user B login website shows user B

The Angular DSCacheFactory just clears browser cache when they expired.

How to i can clear DSCacheFactory user A after logging in user B (session ends).

Comment: Nowhere near enough info I'm afraid. Debug and follow the code. I'd have expected if A was fully setup that you wouldn't be asked for B's login details. So something knows you are signed out, it's after that it's making a booger of it. Normally you'd see destroy in SessionController doing this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I know that post is old, but for future reference if someone need solution to described problem.

You have to check if user is currently signed in with some account and on new sign in attempt just invalidate previous session.

If you override Devise::SessionsController and Create action with that code you should notice expected result. It works correctly with angular devise library

https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise

```
 def create
    if user_signed_in? && params[:user].present?
          sign_out(current_user)
    end
    super
  end
```